# displaying Arabic words incorrectly in FPDF (Python)

Tags: python, pdf, spyder, fpdf, arabic

Problem: 
I am trying to generate a PDF file contains Arabic paragraph using FPDF library. The words in Arabic are displayed incorrectly (it should be from right to left) but they displayed from left to right as English.

what i have tried: 1- download a font which support Arabic letters 2- encode the .txt file, and decode it back to write it in pdf (using *UTF-8*)

**Note:** after the run, txt variable (with encoding='utf-8') contains the words correctly as it is in the .txt file, the problem only in pdf :).

```
pdf = fpdf.FPDF(format='letter')

# Read text file
name = 'mqal.txt'
with open(name, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    txt = f.read()

pdf.add_page()
# freeserif because it support arabic letters
pdf.add_font('FreeSerif', '', 'FreeSerif.ttf', uni=True)
pdf.set_font('FreeSerif', '', 12)
pdf.multi_cell(0, 5, txt,0,'R')
pdf.ln()

pdf.cell(0, 5, 'End')
pdf.output("mqal8.pdf")
```

OUTPUT (IN PDF FILE):

```
ملعت نودو ،ةددحم تاوطخ وأ دعاوق يأ عبتت نأ نود لاقم ةباتكب أدبت نأ كنكمي ديكأتلابو معن
اهلوحتو كراكفأ رصعب أدبتو ،كبوساح مامأ سلجت نأ وه هلعف كيلع ام لك ،لاقملا ةباتك سسأ
،هتباتك تمت عومسم مالكب نوكت ام هبشأ ةجيتنلا نوكتس ام ابلاغ ،بوتكم صن ىلإ ةرشابم
اعبط اذه
لإ
```

it *should* be like this:

```
نعم وبالتأكيد يمكنك أن تبدأ بكتابة مقال دون أن تتبع أي قواعد أو خطوات محددة، ودون تعلم أسس كتابة المقال، كل ما عليك فعله هو أن تجلس أمام حاسوبك، وتبدأ بعصر أفكارك وتحولها مباشرة إلى نص مكتوب، غالبا ما ستكون النتيجة أشبه ما تكون بكلام مسموع تمت كتابته، هذا طبعا إلّا إن كنت خبيرا بكتابة المقالات
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this package to reshape your arabic string

```
import arabic_reshaper # pip install arabic_reshaper

expression = r"^[a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i-j-k-l-m-n-o-p-q-r-s-t-u-v-w-x-y-z-A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z]"
if (re.search(expression, yourstring) is None):
    pdf.add_font('DejaVu', '', 'DejaVuSans.ttf', uni=True)
    pdf.set_font('DejaVu', '', 10)
    arabic_string = arabic_reshaper.reshape(yourstring)
    arabic_string = arabic_string[::-1]
    w = pdf.get_string_width(arabic_string) + 6
    pdf.cell(w, 9, arabic_string, 0, 1, 'L', 0)
```